# Formating a text value into datetime

Tags: excel, datetime

I have a standard text value in csv which I am trying to convert to datetime in Excel. None of the custom formatting works.

Example:

```
2016-01-01T00:00:00Z
2016-01-01T00:15:00Z
2016-01-01T00:30:00Z
2016-01-01T00:45:00Z
2016-01-01T01:00:00Z
2016-01-01T01:15:00Z
2016-01-01T01:30:00Z
```

I tried using @ as a text placeholder but Excel does not allow it. I hope to avoid splitting into two columns. I can already do what I need in R or Python but Excel was supposed to be the easy and fast solution for small tasks like this.

EDIT: I just want to group by month and year later on in a pivot table.

Comment: If the first row was in cell A1, I was able to use "=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,10)," ",MID(A1,12,8))" to pull the date and time. Then this cell is just using long date format and it seems to work. Of course this adds a new column and removes the "T" and "Z" from your original text, so I didn't make this an answer. But I thought maybe this could help if you couldn't find a formatting answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T"," "),"Z","")
```

Or

```
=--REPLACE(LEFT(A1,19),11,1," ")
```

And format as desired.

[image]